# Auto Complete TextBox JQuery PHP MySQL

Tags: php, jquery

I have been referring to [Auto Complete Text Box using JQuery, PHP, MySQL](http://tutsforweb.blogspot.in/2012/05/auto-complete-text-box-with-php-jquery.html?m=1)

My page is split into various PHP Templates. Below is the code:

**Header.php**

```
<!-- JQuery AutoComplete CSS -->
<link href="../css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- JQuery JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery AutoComplete JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

**Main Page**
This page exists inside http://localhost/booking/mainpage.php

```
<tr>
<td class="col-md-4"><label class="control-label">Pooja Name</label></td>
<td class="col-md-8"><input type="text" name="txtPoojaName" id="poojaName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pooja Name"></td>
</tr>
```

I have included the script code in the Main Page at the very end before the ending of the body tag.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#poojaName").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
  });
 });
</script>
```

**autocomplete.php**

This page exists inside http://localhost/booking/autocomplete.php

```
    <?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','pass@1234','srkbs') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="select distinct poojaname from v_poojadetails where poojaname like '%$my_data%' order by poojaname";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    //echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['PoojaName']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

I have tested the autocomplete.php separately and it returns the result set. I guess I am making some mistake in JQuery or some other place.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look in here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
 $("#poojaName").autocomplete({
        source: ["poojaOne","poojaTwo"."poojaThree"],
        selectFirst: true
 })
```

When you are populating your pooja list with `autocomplete.php` you should use `Ajax` to bring the list in and in your `PHP` file you are better off echoing out an array using `json_encode`. Have a look in here http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php to see how to encode a PHP array to JSON.

Comment: is there any other resource? I am using Bootstrap CSS and the solution has its own CSS. I got your point of using AJAX with PHP. Thanks